# MS Access use VBA to Delete a Module from access file

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm looking for a way to Delete a VBA module from an external database file using VBA code.
The external file named "myfile.accdb" has a module named "mod1" I would like to be able to delete that module using VBA code in a separate project.

something like this:
    OpenDatabase("myfile.accdb").Modules("mod1").Delete

working code would be very much appreciated as I have failed to find any my self and failed at writing my own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Ozgrid.com - How to delete a code module](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/delete-module.htm)

This code will remove a code module.

```
Sub DeleteThisModule()

Dim vbCom As Object

    MsgBox "Hi, I will delete myself "
    Set vbCom = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents

    vbCom.Remove VBComponent:= _
    vbCom.Item("Module1")

End Sub
```

So you need a reference to **Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility** and also you need to *Trust Access to VB Editor*

So the code above will get you started, however, you need to reference the external file as the Application